# WinRT ComboBox SelectedValue is null

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have created a class for creating the item to add to combobox

```
public class ComboBoxItemClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

My XAML is as follows for the combobox

```
<TextBlock Text="State"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cbState"/>
```

My C# code in the code-behind is as follows

```
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ComboBoxItemClass> state_items = new List<ComboBoxItemClass>();

        List<State> states = Location.GetStates();
        foreach(State s in states)
        {
            ComboBoxItemClass item = new ComboBoxItemClass() { Text = s.State_Name, Value = s.State_Id };
            state_items.Add(item);
        }
        cbState.ItemsSource = state_items;
        cbState.SelectedValue = 3;
```

The combobox on running in emulator does not show the selected state. On clicking it shows the list of states.

On debugging the selectedvalue is shown to be null despite assigning it a value.
There is no problem with the rest of code and there exists a state with State_Id=3

Comment: Did you try setting `SelectedIndex`? `SelectedValue` is of type `object` and you need to assign it one of the object in your collection to make it work.

Comment: Ya selected index is getting set but that's not what I want

Comment: I tried cbstate.SelectedValue = mystateobject but still it is null

Comment: Try `<ComboBox ... SelectedValuePath="Value" />`

Comment: You're saying `cbstate.SelectedValue = state_items[3]` doesn't work?

Comment: Ya it doesn't work

Comment: Try SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue

Comment: Selecteditem is Not working

Comment: Try it on `Loaded` event of `ComboBox`.

Comment: I checked your code in OnNavigatedTo method. both selectedvalue and selecteditem works. Selecteditem= state_items[3]

Comment: I have just solved the answer in a different manner will be posting it in a few hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this in two ways

The first way is to get the list of states in states variable. Assign this to ComboBox ItemSource. Then get the the State_Id and find the index of that particular state from the same states list and assign it to selected index.

Code Behind as Follows

```
states = Location.GetStates();

cbState.ItemsSource = states;
cbState.SelectedIndex = states.IndexOf(states.Where(x=>x.State_Id==State_Id).First());
```

Second method is as suggested in the comments section

```
 states = Location.GetStates();
 cbState.ItemsSource = states;
 int index=states.IndexOf(states.Where(x=>x.State_Id==State_Id).First());
 cbState.SelectedItem = states[index];
```

XAML is as follows

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbState" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding State_Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Also I would like to post to my fellow WinRT developers that it is not required to create a separate class like ComboBoxItemClass like I did in the question to use combo box. Just get the list of your states, assign it to ItemSource and use any of the above methods.

Also if you want the State_Name and State_Id from the ComboBox you can do this.

```
State mystate=(State)ComboBox.SelectedItem;
```